# How to remove trailing slash from url in nuxt.js?

Tags: nuxt.js

I am looking for a way to redirect all my URLs so that they all do not have a slash in the end. 
I have tried with https://www.npmjs.com/package/@nuxtjs/redirect-module, but it does not redirect correctly.

```
redirect: [
    {
      from: '\/$',
      to: (from, req) => req.url.replace(/\/$/, '')
    }
  ],
```

For example, to change such a url http://localhost:8080/item/test-slug/
This module redirects me to http://localhost:8080/item/test-slug/item/test-slug

Any insight will be welcome. Thanks!

Comment: looking for the same with ?fbclid=, no result yet ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can remove trailing slash with Nuxt latest version(Available since v2.10) with below way:
https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-router/#trailingslash

```
trailingSlash : Type: Boolean or undefined
Default: undefined
Available since: v2.10
ex:
router: {
  trailingSlash: false
}
```

Or with the older version of Nuxt You can use nuxt-trailingslash-module
https://www.npmjs.com/package/nuxt-trailingslash-module

```
npm i nuxt-trailingslash-module
```

Comment: Ive tried. `trailingSlash: false` just does not work. no matter the version

Comment: This does not remove the trailing slash, it makes the route with the trailing slash not work (or the opposite). You still have to handle the redirect.

Answer (score 15):

I've solved this problem using custom middleware. It redirects to url which don't have a slash in the end.

Create **`src/middleware/trailingSlashRedirect.js`**

```
export default function ({ route, redirect }) {
  if (route.path !== '/' && route.path.endsWith('/')) {
    const { path, query, hash } = route;
    const nextPath = path.replace(/\/+$/, '') || '/';
    const nextRoute = { path: nextPath, query, hash };

    redirect(nextRoute);
  }
}
```

Register it in **`nuxt.config.js`**:

```
export default {
  ...
  router: {
    middleware: 'trailingSlashRedirect',
  },
}
```

So you should not use any module to solve this problem. I think it's much better than using third party libs.

Comment: Seemed to only work when adding `trailingSlash: false` to the router as well. Otherwise an error occurred (about duplicate redirection)

Comment: @tmarois you don't need to add `trailingSlash: false`, duplicate redirections will not occur due to custom middleware I mentioned above

Comment: thank you for this, works perfectly with my current set up that uses trailingSlash: false

Comment: Does anyone know why the trailing slash is added in the first place? Strangely, it only adds it to 3 pages on the site I am working on. I used `trailingSlash: false` and it does work when using the internal router but not on initial page load or reload.

Comment: I'm getting duplicate redirect errors as well with this middleware

Comment: Why do you need first condition in your 'if'?
I removed it and left only second condition and it seems to work perfect (with trailingSlash: undefined).

Answer (score 2):

So the only solution I found so far isn't perfect.

Using the [redirect-module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@nuxtjs/redirect-module) , I added the following at the top of my redirects list:

```
{
  // eslint-disable-next-line
  from: '(?!^\/$|^\/[?].*$)(.*\/[?](.*)$|.*\/$)',
  to: (from, req) => {
    const base = req._parsedUrl.pathname.replace(/\/$/, '');
    const search = req._parsedUrl.search;
    return base + (search != null ? search : '');
  }
},
```

Also in *nuxt.config.js* I made sure to add the trailing slash configuration. ([See the doc](https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-router/#trailingslash))

```
router: {
  trailingSlash: false
},
```

**Note:**
It redirect all URLS ending with `'/'` with query parameters, but it doesn't match the home page `'/'` *(which seems to be handled somehow)*

The following will redirect the following:

- `'/blog/'` to `'/blog'`
- `'/blog/?a=b'` to `'/blog?a=b'`
- `'/blog/foo/'` to `'/blog/foo'`
- `'/blog/foo/?a=b'` to `'/blog/foo?a=b'`
- `'/'` to `'/'`. --> *won't work*
- `'/?a=b'` to `'/?a=b'`. --> *won't work*

I made a test list [available here](https://regex101.com/r/PYR3vt/5)

---

**Explanation of the regex**

It might not be perfect since I'm not a Regex expert but:

```
'(?!^\/$|^\/[?].*$)(.*\/[?](.*)$|.*\/$)'
```

It's broken it 2 pieces: 1 exclusion, and 1 inclusion.

The exclusion: `(?!^\/$|^\/[?].*$)`, consist of a check to exclude standalone trailing comma (`/`) or standalone trailing comma with query string `/?foo=bar` routes. It's used mainly for the home page.

The inclusion: `(.*\/[?](.*)$|.*\/$)`, consists of checking for the trialing comma (`/blog/`) or a trailing comma with query string (`/blog/?foo=bar`)

Comment: this is great! i think the regex could be simplified to: `from: '.{1,}\/([?].*)?$'`. this matches any path that has at least 1 character before a trailing slash at the end - with an optional querystring.

Answer (score 1):

For those who are looking for a solution working on **Nuxt 3**, you have to use a middleware.

Create a file named `trailingSlash.global.js` in the `middleware` directory and copy/paste this inside :

```
export default defineNuxtRouteMiddleware((to) => {
  if (to.path.slice(-1) === '/') {
    return navigateTo({...to,
      path: to.path.slice(0, -1)
    })
  }
});
```

Comment: What's the point of this? Trailing slashes are being removed automatically in Nuxt 3.

Comment: It doesn't, I have three project running on Nuxt 3 and none of them removes the trailing slash automatically.. Could be because I use the "pages:extend" hook, I don't really know..

Comment: 500
Infinite redirect in navigation guard

Comment: For Nuxt 3 with SSR on Apache, the solution is in your `.htaccess` file as described here https://stackoverflow.com/a/77699881/1454622 . The trick is that we want to display no trailing slash BUT ALSO serve that directory's `index.html` file.

Answer (score 0):

In nuxt.config.js as @Hardik Shah and @tsnkff says

```
router: {
  trailingSlash: false
},
```

For other needs use ufo package https://github.com/unjs/ufo#withouttrailingslash

**withoutTrailingSlash**
Ensures url does not ends with a trailing slash

```
// Result: /foo
withoutTrailingSlash('/foo/')
// Result: /path?query=true
withoutTrailingSlash('/path/?query=true', true)
```

**withTrailingSlash**
Ensures url ends with a trailing slash

```
// Result: /foo/
withTrailingSlash('/foo')
// Result: /path/?query=true
withTrailingSlash('/path?query=true', true)
```

and other helpful functions are in unjs/ufo package that created by nuxt team and is used in nuxt code also.

Answer (score 0):

For those who are having problem with the top answer (creating custom middleware to redirect) using **Nuxt 2.15.8**.
If you are getting the *too many redirects* error, it may be caused by Nuxt doing its own internal redirection to end-slash variant (from *test-slug* to *test-slug/*). Nuxt decides to add a slash when you have the same name folder in the *static* folder as you page filename.

The solution is renaming either of those.