# Nuxt 3 - how to remove trailing slash?

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

In Nuxt 3, how to remove trailing slash from urls?

In Nuxt 2, it was done by adding these lines to `nuxt.config.js`:

```
router: {
    trailingSlash: false
  }
```

What is the equivalent in Nuxt 3?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [nuxt docs](https://v3.nuxtjs.org/api/configuration/nuxt-config#router), and [vue router docs](https://router.vuejs.org/api/interfaces/routeroptions.html#strict). It seems that `trailingSlash` has been replaced by `strict` which controls "Whether to disallow a trailing slash or not.".

However, according to the docs, the default value is `false`, meaning that without any configuration you should be able to visit pages both with and without trailing slash.

Comment: Just to make it easier for anyone, the replacement code in nuxt.config is  {router:{options:{strict: true}}}

Comment: This does not do anything basically. Your routes are just not going to render on a trailing slash request. So you can still visit `/page/` it will just display empty. Check https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt/issues/15462#issuecomment-1407374859

Answer (score 6):

Based on @evg_ny's answer, I created this version which will work with Nuxt3 to redirect routes with the trailing slash to the non-trailing slash variant:

```js
export default defineNuxtRouteMiddleware((to, from) => {
  if (to.path !== '/' && to.path.endsWith('/')) {
    const { path, query, hash } = to;
    const nextPath = path.replace(/\/+$/, '') || '/';
    const nextRoute = { path: nextPath, query, hash };
    return navigateTo(nextRoute, { redirectCode: 301 });
  }
})
```

Save it in `./middleware/redirect-trailing-slash.global.js` and it'll work globally

Comment: Thanks, I mentioned it in https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt/issues/15462#issuecomment-1407374859

Comment: Awesome.

I wish Nuxt shipped with a bunch of default middleware like Laravel

Answer (score 2):

If your goal is to remove all trailing slashes and redirect to the page without trailing slashes then you can use middleware like this:

```js
export default function ({ route, redirect }) {
  if (route.path !== '/' && route.path.endsWith('/')) {
    const { path, query, hash } = route;
    const nextPath = path.replace(/\/+$/, '') || '/';
    const nextRoute = { path: nextPath, query, hash };

    return navigateTo(nextRoute, { redirectCode: 301 });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For Nuxt 3 using SSR, the directory *does exist* and Apache *is supposed to* serve that directory's physical `index.html` file. This is different than the client-side rendering which works by serving the *root* `index.html` for everything.

The solution is to 1) turn off directory trailing slash, and then 2) rewrite the request to request that directory's `index.html` file.

My .htaccess w/ before and after:

```
# BEFORE
#RewriteEngine On
#RewriteBase /
#RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#RewriteRule . /index.html [L] # For non-SSR, serve the root index.html


# AFTER, WITH SSR
DirectorySlash Off # Turn off trailing slash

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d # Omit for SSR because there is a physical directory
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1/index.html [L]
#RewriteRule . /index.html [L] # Omit for SSR because the served file is the requested dir's index.html (rather than the root index.html)
```

Comment: This has been my challenge for a long time. I appreciate your contribution.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed the middleware solution contains a security risk. If you run the server, a url like `https://mynuxtproject.com//evil.example.com/` could redirect to a third party site, because you'll try to redirect to `//evil.example.com`.