# Inconsistency in the path value before and after page reload in Nuxt.js

Tags: vue.js, path, nuxt.js, vue-router

In my Nuxt.js application, I've noticed that before reloading the page, the path value accessed using

```
this.$route.path ="/mytasks",
```

but after reloading the page, the path value changes to

```
"/mytasks/".
```

How to solve the inconsistency in the path value before and after page reload in Nuxt?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Nuxt 3 - how to remove trailing slash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74261193/nuxt-3-how-to-remove-trailing-slash)